# A few questions about spinors and gamma matrices

Tags: conventions, supersymmetry, spinors, dirac-matrices, grassmann-numbers

I am following [BUSSTEPP Lectures on Supersymmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109172) and trying to show that the Wess-Zumino action is invariant under SUSY transformations. I encountered the following questions about spinors and gamma matrices.

Let $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ be any two Grassmann-valued Majorana spinors. Here, $\bar{\epsilon}$ means the Majorana adjoint, i.e. $\bar{\epsilon}=\epsilon^{T}\mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the charge conjugation matrix.

I want to prove the following identities

$$\bar{\epsilon}\eta=\bar{\eta}\epsilon,\quad\bar{\epsilon}\gamma_{5}\eta=\bar{\eta}\gamma_{5}\epsilon,\quad\bar{\epsilon}\gamma^{\mu}\eta=-\eta\gamma^{\mu}\epsilon,\quad\bar{\epsilon}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\eta=\bar{\eta}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\epsilon$$

---

I just found that they are equation (3.51) of [Supergravity by Daniel Z. Freedman](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/supergravity/B7EEC3E37A39AB6E6625850857B96AA7).

Comment: Are you using any chirality conditions on your gammas?

Comment: Have you reminded yourself how fermion mass terms achieve hermiticity?

Comment: @R.Rankin What are chirality conditions? I am not assuming anything. If I do a SUSY variation on the Lagrangian, I will end up with "inner products" shown above. But I cannot prove $(\bar{\epsilon}\eta)^{\dagger}=\bar{\epsilon}\eta$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Oh Thank you for reminding me that, but that is not a mass term. Is the third identity also correct?

Comment: I doubt it. Recall $\gamma^0$ is hermitian and the spacelike ones antihermitian.

Comment: I often use chirality and hermiticity interchangably (in an abuse of terminology) So @CosmasZachos has picked up my point.

Comment: @CosmasZachos and R.Rankin I am sorry $\psi$ is a Majorana spinor. There is a table showing the signs on page 48 of "Supergravity" by Daniel Z. Freedman.

Comment: OK, you skipped the bar on the vector. You still want a proof?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes I still want a proof. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spinors are real and your [Dirac matrices in the Majorana representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Majorana_basis) are  imaginary, so

- $\gamma^0$ is Hermitean A(ntisymmetric)
- $\gamma^i$ are Antihermitean S(ymmetric)
- $\gamma^5$ is Hermitean A(ntisymmetric)   $\leadsto$ check this from the above!

Thus 
$$
\bar{\epsilon}\eta= i\epsilon^T \gamma^0 \eta =-i\eta^T \gamma^{0~~T} \epsilon =i\eta^T \gamma^{0 }\epsilon = \bar{\eta} \epsilon ,
$$
So now you got your baseline. Make sure you appreciate every step.

The rest follow trivially from the above properties of the *γ* matrices and
the above properties, so supplanting $\gamma^0$, you now have
$$(\gamma^0 \gamma^5)^T= \gamma^5 \gamma^0= -\gamma^0 \gamma^5,$$
just like for the scalar, so $\bar{\epsilon}\gamma_{5}\eta=\bar{\eta}\gamma_{5}\epsilon$.
(Anti-)likewise, 
$$
(\gamma^0 \gamma^\mu)^T= \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu,
$$
where you can marvel at how the time-like and space like parts synchronize to yield a uniform answer, hence $\bar{\epsilon}\gamma^{\mu}\eta=-\bar{\eta}\gamma^{\mu}\epsilon$.
Finally, for the axial, $\gamma^5$ flips the sign to yield 
$\bar{\epsilon}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\eta=\bar{\eta}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\epsilon$ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already derived those identities. I thought you were going to prove the generic identity (3.51) from the book Supergravity by Freedman.

Comment: I don't have that book! If you want an identity proven, you should at least provide it... If it is the generic string of  γ matrices, it should follow easily from the combinatoric nature of their transpose and rearrangement of the resulting strings...